# Nodes won't position as they should in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, nodes

When I use the example of the `pgfplots` manual it looks different from what is shown in the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=Snap to nearest for scatter plots]
\addplot+[only marks]
coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3)}
node[pos=0,pin=0:0] {}
node[pos=0.1, pin=90 :0.1 ] {}
node[pos=0.2, pin=200:0.2 ] {}
node[pos=0.3, pin=135:0.3 ] {}
node[pos=0.4, pin=0
:0.4 ] {}
node[pos=0.5, pin=60 :0.5 ] {}
node[pos=0.75,pin=180:0.75] {}
node[pos=1,pin=90 :1] {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

This part `pos=0.75` etc. is obviously not working. What am I doing wrong?

I use TeXnicCenter 1.0 RC1 with MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: The code compiles fine for me, and produces the figure on p241 of the manual- it sounds like you need to update your distribution. You can check the age of your packages by adding `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}`

Comment: Updating  the packages helped! Thanks a lot and sorry to have bothered you with such a question. Felt like I installed all that stuff yesterday, but seems like I'm working longer on my thesis than I would have guessed :-)

Comment: No problem! These things *always* take longer than you think- I usually estimate how long I think a task will take, and then allow at least double :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As cmhughes suggested, you need a more recent version of pgfplots: support for `pos=0.75` and its variants has been added in version 1.5.1 (can be obtained via CTAN, TeX package managers or http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/).